# Partition data recovery

Tags: data-recovery

I recently installed Ubuntu. Unfortunately during the process all the partitions have been erased which contained my backup data. Is there any way of recovering the data? It was almost 400 GB of data.

Comment: What was the format of the lost partition -- ntfs? ext4?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try. You will need:

1. Live CD (USB drive) with Ubuntu (for simplicity I will call it *Live CD*)
2. External HDD to backup recovered data (I will call it *ExtHDD*)
3. A lot of luck

**The steps:**

1. Boot from the Live CD, and connect to your network (the HDD which will be recovered I will call it `/dev/sda`)
2. Plug in the ExtHDD (aka `/dev/sdb`), and mount it
3. Install `testdisk` (`sudo apt-get install testdisk`), and follow the instructions described [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).